# Python recursion exercises

Tags: python, recursion, binary

"Write a function bin_rep(n) that returns a string with the binary representation of n.

Extend bin_rep(n) to create base_rep(n, k) to give a string representing non-netavie integer n in base k, where 2 <= k <= 10. In base k, the only digits allowed are {0, ..., k-1}.

For a list of distinct integers, L, define switches(L) as the number of pairs in L that are not in increasing order. For example, switches([6, 1, 4]) returns 2, since (6, 1) and (6, 4) are out of order."

Above is the extra credit exercise in lab class. I can't understand how to write those codes at all. I do have the bin_rep(n) function from class notes, but that is about it. Please help. This exercise is not marked at all, but I would like to know how it can be written. Thanks.

```
def bin_rep(n):

    if n == 0:
        return ['']
    else:
        short_strings = bin_rep(n - 1)

        strings = []
        for s in short_strings:
            strings.append('0' + s)
        for s in short_strings:
            strings.append('1' + s)

        return strings
```

Comment: SO is not for solving your exercises

Comment: So think about how and why those pieces of code work. (Note that the word "code" is uncountable, so you can't have "those codes", only "those pieces of code".)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Well, you can have "those codes" when you're talking about other senses of the word, like ciphers. And you can even at least questionably use it when dealing with multiple separate codebases. But when dealing with one program, yeah, it's "this code" or "some code", not "those codes" or "some codes".

Comment: Meanwhile, the function you gave _doesn't_ give the binary representation of `n`, it gives all of the binary strings of up to `n` bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than give you the code, I'll explain how to solve this, so you can write it yourself.

First, note that, contrary to your description, `bin_rep` does *not* give the binary representation of the number `n`; instead, it gives a list of all of the binary strings of up to `n` digits.

So, assuming you want to do the same thing—that is, give a list of all the base-`k` strings of up to `n` digits—you have to identify where the "base 2-ness" comes in.

Look at this code:

```
    for s in short_strings:
        strings.append('0' + s)
    for s in short_strings:
        strings.append('1' + s)
```

That does something for the digit `0`, and then for the digit `1`. Those are the two digits of base 2. So, to make this work for base 3 instead, it would be:

```
    for s in short_strings:
        strings.append('0' + s)
    for s in short_strings:
        strings.append('1' + s)
    for s in short_strings:
        strings.append('2' + s)
```

But for arbitrary base `k`, you have to do this for every digit from `0` up to (but not including) `k`. So, you're going to write some loop that goes through all the numbers in that (half-open) range, and then, instead of repeating this two-liner, just use it once, as a nested loop inside that loop over the digits.

Also, of course, instead of hardcoding the string `'0'`, you're going to need to write the string representation of the digit. (You can't add a number to a string; you have to convert the number to its string representation, and then add *that* to the string.)

Also keep in mind that you can't just call `base_rep(n - 1)`, because `base_rep` takes two arguments. What should the second argument be?